# Proving this Differential Equation has one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose q(x) is an n-th degree polynomial and consider the following DE:

x(dy/dx) + y = q(x)

Show that there is only one solution to this differential equation that is, itself, a polynomial. What is the degree of this polynomial?

---

I think I have an intuition on how to do it but can't come to an answer. My attempt was:

Realizing the left side could be written as (xy)'

-> (xy)' = q(x)

xy = integral(q(x)dx)

xy = [h(x)]/(n+1), where h(x) is a polynomial with degree n+1

y = [h(x)]/x(n+1)

... and I'm stuck.

This is how I went about solving to show the solution was a polynomial. As for existence and uniqueness, I assume I would just set dy/dx = q(x)/x - y/x and show where f(x,y) is continuous and where f'(x,y) is continuous?
Hopefully I'm not completely off base here. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you integrate using
$$xy=\int q(x)dx+C=h(x)+C.$$
$h$ is itself a polynomial, of degree one more than $q$.

Dividing by $x$,

$$y=\frac{h(x)+C}x.$$
For the latter expression to be a polynomial, $h(x)+C$ must have no constant term, so that $C=0$ and the solution is unique.

Then,
$$h(x)=\frac{q_n}{n+1}x^{n}+\frac{q_{n-1}}{n}x^{n-1}+...\frac{q_2}3x^2+\frac{q_1}2x+q_0.$$